# How to get separate Gatling report for each step of the simulation?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have the ramp up test that increases the amount of users every time in Gatling.
For the user's injections I am using these methods:

```
setUp(
Test.inject(incrementConcurrentUsers(1) 
  .times(4)
  .eachLevelLasting(20)
  .separatedByRampsLasting(1)
  .startingFrom(4)
))
```

[image: graph]

So according to this screenshot, I need to have 4 additional reports for every user's change during a specific time for one simulation.
Is there any way to generate a separate report for every level with the user's change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in gatling itself.
Nevertheless, you can take your simulation.log and process it through bash and awk for generate simulation.log for each level and then create report via https://github.com/nuxeo/gatling-report